MySQL table_open_cache miss 100% on query spikes
We encountered a situation where we had multiple connections opened to our DB, which seems to cause a high rate of open table cache misses.
I would expect that in this kind of situation we see 100% cache utilisation, but the opposite happened, hit rate was reduced to 0%.
When query rate went down we saw that cache usage increased back to 100%
Do you have any idea what might cuase that?
